# Docker container port timeout

Tags: networking, docker, synology, plex

I have plex running inside a docker container. I have mapped port 32400 from inside the container to port 32450 on the host. I cannot connect to it.

```
root@Media:~# curl localhost:32450
^C
```

but... if I run:

```
root@Media:~# curl -4 localhost:32450
<html><head><script>window.location = window.location.href.match(/(^.+\/)[^\/]*$/)[1] + 'web/index.html';</script><title>Unauthorized</title></head><body><h1>401 Unauthorized</h1></body></html>
```

I've been scratching my head for a while with this. Why do I have to force curl to use ipv4? How can I connect to that port from a browser, as it currently just times out.

Thanks.